# is `cap` a reserved word? - zsh completion?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

I'm trying to create a Capistrano [mutilstage](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension) completion for ZSH:

```sh
$ cap |
production staging


$ cap production |
deploy                       -- Deploy a new release
deploy:bundle                -- Bundle
...
```

#### Completion code:

```sh
#compdef cap
#autoload

# /Users/pablo/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/capistrano_custom/_capistrano_custom

local curcontext="$curcontext" state line ret=1
local -a _configs

_arguments -C \
  '1: :->cmds' \
  '2:: :->args' && ret=0

_cap_tasks() {
  if [[ ! -f .cap_tasks~ ]]; then
    echo "\nGenerating .cap_tasks~..." > /dev/stderr
    cap -v --tasks | grep '#' | cut -d " " -f 2 > .cap_tasks~
  fi
  cat .cap_tasks~
}

_cap_stages() {
  find config/deploy -name \*.rb | cut -d/ -f3 | sed s:.rb::g
}

case $state in
  cmds)
    if [[ -d config/deploy ]]; then
      compadd `_cap_stages`
    else
      compadd `_cap_tasks`
    fi
    ret=0
    ;;
  args)
    compadd `_cap_tasks`
    ret=0
    ;;
esac

return ret
```

#### The problem:

`#compdef cap` doesn't work. If I type `cap` and [TAB] it doesn't execute the completion, but with other words (i.e. `shipit`) works fine.

Any ideas?

### Solution:

[cap is really a reserved word](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fcap-Module) and it seems that we can't use it with `#compdef cap`.

I'm wondering how [cap](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/src/_cap) and [capistrano](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/capistrano/) completions worked before (maybe an old version of ZSH).

- Solution dotfiles code: [capistrano_custom](https://github.com/phstc/dotfiles/tree/master/oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/capistrano_custom)
- Solution oh-my-zsh/PR: [#2471](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/pull/2471)

Both solutions use `shipit` instead of `cap`.

```sh
$ shipit |
production staging

$ shipit production |
deploy                       -- Deploy a new release
deploy:bundle                -- Bundle
...
```

Comment: *"Any ideas?"* -- Use `xcap`, or some other suitable name.

Comment: `alias xcap="cap"` I tried, but it still not working. ZSH doesn't like completions with `cap`.

Comment: An alias isn't going to work; the original name must also not be reserved.

Comment: I added a "solution" in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Pablo, how can I use you custom plugin?

Comment: Hi @across, while it's not merged in, you can use it as a custom plugin, as I do. Have a look at https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/pull/2471#issuecomment-77750188

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `cap` is a ZSH builtin. Quoting [from zsh docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fcap-Module):

> The zsh/cap module is used for manipulating POSIX.1e (POSIX.6)
>   capability sets. *[...]*. The builtins in this module are:
>
> **cap [ capabilities ]** Change the shell’s process capability sets to the
>   specified capabilities, otherwise display the shell’s current
>   capabilities.

Comment: Thank you. So, none of these scripts https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/src/_cap and https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/capistrano/_capistrano work?

Comment: No, unless you use `xcap` or the like for autocompletion. You could also try to unload the `cap` with `zmodload -u cap` (if it is a module) or recompile `zsh` without `cap` (if it was enabled at compile time). The latter is not a great idea, unless you are absolutely sure you will never need `cap`.

Comment: `zmodload: no such module cap` I think it isn't a module. :/

Comment: In that case, find another keyword for autocompletion. Perhaps `capi` or `xcap`…